# calculate the distance between multiple GPS position w.r.t one reference

Tags: python, distance, gmt

I have 80 points one line that crosses one particular point. I want to calculate the distance between that reference point and each station and it should be positive and negative.
I tried following way but it gives me only positive distance value,

```
stla = st[0].stats.sac['stla'] #station lat
stlo = st[0].stats.sac['stlo'] #station lon
#crossover distance
crlo = 104.499765143 
crla = 29.4742139251
dist1 = gps2dist_azimuth(stla,stlo, crla,crlo)
dist1=dist1[0]`
```

I got this output (in meters)

```
`1549.9072755468023
 2314.5301492042786
 1978.8805972408672
 604.7927668562546
 195.07039250670383
 2177.129827481811
 212.6443078339846
 863.9573297833116
 1615.5449194502921
 1219.2825679960995
 1564.226848063852
 2600.316245974806
 741.5826151164387
 665.5972988769541
 2335.6051118556975
```

What I expected it should be like this (In Km, please ignore the units difference):

```
0.5983164169
0.637797120571
0.732341381346  
0.776296768282  
0.83927019696   
0.864898580629  
0.927615280754  
0.9785794379    
1.07543888694   
1.09081523648   
1.14869546005   
1.18406238008   
1.25599403922   
1.33394492802   
1.3999813227    
1.44882008293
1.51207083251
1.57852778971
```

I can calculate from GMT with this command by keeping one point as the center point

```
gmt project 1.txt -C104.499765143/29.4742139251 -A87.64 -Fpq -Q
```

1.txt is the station's position and -C is the center point,-A represents the azimuth.

Comment: To answer your question properly: How would you define a negative distance? The distance between two points on a sphere is by definition always positive.
And in your sample output you also have a result in m and in your desired output you are looking for km. Is this a question? The conversion between the two should be pretty straightforward: 1/1000

Comment: @CHecht thanks for the comment. Please ignore the units difference. Here I want to keep one point in the center and calculate the spatial distance w.r.t that reference location and azimuth. It is one line command in GMT But I am trying to use Python for all scripts.

Comment: If you are saying with respect to azimuth: Why can't you just compare latitudes and use that to determine whether the number (I wouldn't call it distance) should be positive or negative. I am not familiar with GMT, so that unfortunately doesn't help me.

Comment: You want to use https://pypi.org/project/haversine/